# Sails.js - How to setup the sails socket config?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, sails.js

I have studied sockets, socket.io and sails yesterday and I have to say that I'm pretty lost. I've never used them before. I thought I understand but I'm not sure anymore.

I have based my work on http://socket.io/get-started/chat/. I'm working with the framework Sails.js, which add its own method to deal with sockets and so on.

In `config/sockets.js` we have a `onConnect` and `onDisconnect` methods. See https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/sails.config/sails.config.sockets.md and (source code) https://gist.github.com/Vadorequest/568afc14294f1448ab55

I will compare sails and socket.io, let's take this code:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});
```

When the socket.io is open (connection) it defines `listeners` like `socket.on('disconnect')` which are waiting for an emmited request, from the client or the server using `socket.emit` method.

What I thought is that the sails `onConnect` is equivalent to the socket.io `io.on(connection)`. Then the sails `onDisconnect` method is equivalent to `socket.on('disconnect')`, inside the `io.on(connection)`, it would be like a shortcut, sails proper way to handle this specific event and respect its standards (method starting by `on`).

But I've shown my code to a friend who has already worked with socket.io and sails and he tells me I'm wrong and what I'm doing is defining a listener inside another listener which would result in a messy mess (at least).

I would like to know if I misunderstood how to setup sails sockets.

If I'm wrong I'll cry but I'll get over it.

Answer (score 4):

My first impression was actually right, so Sails hide the `socket.io` logic for us, these two codes are equivalent, the first one using `socket.io` and the second using Sails `config/sockets.js` way:

```
// Socket.io way
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});

// Sails way (config/sockets.js), hide the socket.io logic. (Facade design pattern)
module.exports.sockets = {
  onDisconnect: function(session, socket) {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  }
}
```

The same way, the Sails `onConnect` method is equivalent to

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('connect', function() { 
        console.log('user connected');
     });
});
```